# Grails BigDecimal constraints not working

Tags: grails, constraints

I am using Grails version 2.3.3, and groovy version 2.1.8.

I am using an online tutorial to help learn Grails web dev, and I have created a domain class with the following constraints

```
package racetrack



class Race {

static constraints = {
    name(blank:false, maxSize:50)
    city(blank:false)
    state(inList:["GA", "NC", "SC", "VA"])
    startDate()
    distance(min: 0.0) 
    cost(min: new BigDecimal(0.0), max: new BigDecimal(100.0))
    maxRunners(min:0, max:100000)
}

String name
Date startDate
String city
String state
BigDecimal distance
BigDecimal cost 
Integer maxRunners

}
```

I'm using scaffolding so I have full CRUD functionality. The problem is, when I go to create a new Race, the app allows me to input values like "-1" in both the distance and cost fields, and values like "200" for the cost field. I noticed that the Integer field maxRunners was working correctly, as it displays a warning message if I try to put in -1 maxRunners. I changed the cost field to be of type Integer, and then the constraints started working.

Why is this happening? I copy and pasted the code from the tutorial into my text file and the constraints to not work for BigDecimal type fields.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for the `min` and `max` constraints, the parameter must be

> a class that implements java.lang.Comparable. The type of the value must be the same as the property.

so I can't see any reason why your definition shouldn't work. As a workaround, you could try replacing this

```
cost(min: new BigDecimal(0.0), max: new BigDecimal(100.0))
```

with

```
cost(range: 0..100)
```

and you could replace this constraint:

```
distance(min: 0.0)
```

with a custom validator, e.g.

```
distance validator: {
    it >= 0.0
}
```

I've just noticed the following oddity which appears before the 2 problematic constraints

```
startDate()
```

Perhaps replacing it with either:

```
startDate(nullable: true)
```

or

```
startDate(nullable: false)
```

might fix the problem?

Comment: I think I've learned a little bit more about what's going wrong, though I still don't know why. 

When I ran **grails run-app**, the server booted up, I went to make a new Race **without making any of the changes you suggested** and the constraints worked! I could not make a race with a cost of -1 or distance of -1. But when I changed the code to one of your suggestions, and grails recompiled my Race.groovy code, the constraints didn't work! I played around with it and figured out that no matter what I write for constraints, they only work when the server is **first** started. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that domain class constraints are not automatically reloaded because they require a change to the database schema.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't Groovy use `java.math.BigDecimal` by default? Could you change `new BigDecimal(0.0)` to simply `0.0` and `new BigDecimal(100.00)` to `100.00` like this:

```
cost(min: 0.0, max: 100.0)
```

[Here is the documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Math) that states:

> To support the 'least surprising' approach, groovy literals with decimal points are instantiated as java.math.BigDecimal types rather than binary floating point types (Float, Double).

Also, you could try forcing it by using the `G` suffix like this:

```
cost(min: 0.0G, max: 100.0G)
```